# May the cname-string part of an AS-REQ contain the domain?

Tags: kerberos

In a network capture between a Windows client and an Active Directory server, I see that the field `cname-string` contains `user@domain.com` (to be precise, it is the field `as-req` -> `req-body` -> `cname` -> `cname-string` -> `CNameString`).

According to [RFC 4130](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt) in Section 5.2.2.  Realm and PrincipalName:

> name-string:
>         This field encodes a sequence of components that form a name, each
>         component encoded as a KerberosString.  Taken together, a
>         PrincipalName and a Realm form a principal identifier.  Most
>         PrincipalNames will have only a few components (typically one or
>         two).

Also in Section 5.3.  Tickets:

> cname
>         This field contains the name part of the client's principal
>         identifier.

To me, that means cname should only contain the username without the domain. The domain is obtained via the realm and together they form the principal identifier (basically paraphrasing the RFC here).

Am I wrong? Have you come across setups where the domain was part of the cname? How did the target service handle that? I see that the realm is added again to the cname, resulting user@domain.com@domain.com, which obviously prevents a correct matching.

Comment: Is this Active Directory?

Comment: Yes, this is Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one case when this can happen: enterprise principals. You should see the `NT-ENTERPRISE` somehwere as well as `CANONICALIZE` bit set. The AD contains an `upnSuffix` for the supplied enterprise principal. See also [RFC 6806](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6806.html) for this.

Comment: Indeed, the reason seems to be the name type `NT-ENTERPRISE` (in Windows it's called `KRB_NT_ENTERPRISE_PRINCIPAL`, in Wireshark it's `kRB5-NT-ENTERPRISE-PRINCIPAL`). However, in my case, no upnSuffix is set, so that is optional.

Comment: Windows always sets this principal type and the canocalize flag because it does not know at login time wether the passed principal is an implicit or explicit one. The KDC will do the rest for the client.